# SQL DISTINCT Column with 2nd Criteria as datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have on just started learning SQL in SQL Server Management Studio and getting thrown into the deep end.

I just need unique `DriverID` that has a `LogoffTime` in the last 3 month, with the headings included below.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    Dr.DriverName, Dr.DriverNumber, Dr.DriverID, 
    DL.DriverID, DL.LogoffTime,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DL.DriverID ORDER BY DL.LogoffTime DESC) AS rn
FROM 
    Taxihistory.dbo.DriverLogon DL, Taxihistory.dbo.Driver Dr 
WHERE 
    DL.DriverID = Dr.DriverID
    AND DL.LogoffTime <= '20180931'
    AND rn = 1 
ORDER BY 
    DL.LogoffTime DESC;
```

I am currently getting this error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'rn'

Comment: what's the datatype and format of the logofftime in your DriverLogon Table? .. this can actually be accomplished with simple `INNER JOIN`and just use `BETWEEN MONTH(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(DriverLogon.LogoffTime  - 3)` as your condition

Comment: Data in the LogoffTime Column look like this
2018-12-27 06:00:37.460

Comment: Okay good, i know you already marked someones answer as the correct one. you may want to check  also on the query I posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to explore CTE (Common Table Expression) option, you may also be able to achieve this with CTE. You can try something like below:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT dr.drivername,
                    dr.drivernumber,
                    dr.driverid,
                    dl.logofftime,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dl.driverid
                                       ORDER BY dl.logofftime DESC) AS rn
                    FROM taxihistory.dbo.driverlogon dl
                         INNER JOIN taxihistory.dbo.driver dr
                                    ON dr.driverid = dl.driverid
                    WHERE dl.logofftime <= Convert(datetime, '2018-09-30') ) 

SELECT tbl.drivername,
       tbl.drivernumber,
       tbl.driverid,
       tbl.logofftime
FROM CTE tbl
WHERE tbl.rn = 1 
ORDER BY tbl.logofftime DESC;
```

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The column 'driverid' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
LogoffTime is a date/time Type

Comment: Check the latest edit. I haven't run the query as I did not set up the table structure, but this may give you some idea.

Comment: Perfect you are a GOD among men!

Comment: if that doesn't work you may want to try putting this in your where condition:  WHERE dl.logofftime <=  '2018-09-30 00:00:00.000'

Comment: Anytime :) Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. Neither can you use `row_number()` there. You have to wrap the query with the `row_number()` in a subquery and select from that.

```
SELECT x.drivername,
       x.drivernumber,
       x.driverid,
       x.logofftime
       FROM (SELECT dr.drivername,
                    dr.drivernumber,
                    dr.driverid,
                    dl.logofftime,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dl.driverid
                                       ORDER BY dl.logofftime DESC) rn
                    FROM taxihistory.dbo.driverlogon dl
                         INNER JOIN taxihistory.dbo.driver dr
                                    ON dr.driverid = dl.driverid
                    WHERE dl.logofftime <= '20180930') x
       WHERE x.rn = 1 
       ORDER BY x.logofftime DESC;
```

It is also advisable to use explicit join syntax. And I do hope, that `driverlogon.logofftime` is not an `[n][var]char` but some date/time type.

Comment: Had to make sure but it is date/time type

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.

Comment: @JacobBerry: Don't know when you copied it. But i had a stray comma after `taxihistory.dbo.driverlogon dl`, which I already edited out. Could be the cause of the error you get. Please try again with the query as it stands now.

Comment: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The column 'driverid' was specified multiple times for 'x'.
I really appreciate your help but Im having a real hard time wrapping my head around this. Im doing some research into what you gave me so I can understand it better

Comment: @JacobBerry: Ah yeah, you had it in there twice and I didn't notice that and copied it as it was. I removed one instance, as I believe you don't need it two times. See the edit.

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
LogoffTime is a date/time Type

Data in the LogoffTime Column look like this
2018-12-27 06:00:37.460

Comment: @JacobBerry: September only has 30 days. But you used `'20180931'`. Maybe you want `'20180930'`? See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the logon from the last 3 months up to the current date by doing so:

```
SELECT Dr.DriverName, Dr.DriverNumber, Dr.DriverID, DL.DriverID, DL.LogoffTime
FROM Taxihistory.dbo.DriverLogon DL, 
INNER JOIN Taxihistory.dbo.Driver Dr ON DL.DriverID = Dr.DriverID
WHERE DL.LogOffTime < DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
ORDER BY DL.LogoffTime DESC;
```